# Arduino STM32 bluepill generate PPM

Tags: arduino, stm32, stm32f1

does anyone knows is there a way to generate PPM (CPPM/PPMSUM) on STM32 Bluepill Arduino?

Tnx in advance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. Just set up the hardware timers and their interrupts so you get the desired output. It's just a matter of programming; I'm sure you can take it from here.